# How do I dynamically set the checked property on a checkbox in Aurelia based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, aurelia

I have a list of objects that I am using to create a menu with checkboxes. I want to set the checked property on these checkboxes on load by basing it off of an Enum value that the object model has.

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
<li repeat.for="item of items">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="${item.status == 'EnumValue' ? 'checked' : '' />
</li>
```

This did not work. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `checked.bind="<expression>"` syntax to bind boolean expressions to properties. [[Documentation]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/2)

In this case: `<input type="checkbox" checked.bind="item.status == 'EnumValue'" />`

Gist demo: https://gist.run/?id=b9a2929bdd34061795b90ddbfd745e75